# Git try to merge code with code already in destination branch

Tags: git, merge

I recently try to merge from dev branch to master branch. However, merge shows the commits that are already in the master branch. I would like to know what are the possible reason for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Merging branches uses fast-forward by default, so all the commits from both branches will be now part of your master branch, ordered by the timestamp of each commit.

Use `git merge --no-ff master dev_branch` to avoid using fast-forward.